# How to consume the soul of an object

Tags: c++

I have a movable type that **has no default constructor** and I want to take away its internal data and destroy them.  My thought was to `std::move` it to a temporary, and let the temporary destructor happen (to destroy the internal data), leaving the original now-empty object behind.

The closest I've got makes use of a little helper template that's sole purpose is to destroy its argument (which is why it's passed by value, and why the body of the function is empty.)  (Maybe there's a better way?)  Then I call `std::move` to move the internals of the original object to a temp, and the temp will be destroyed, destroying the original internals, and leaving the object in whatever state it is in after having its internals moved to another object.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void reset(T t) {}
};

reset(std::move(somevar));
```

For example, if I had a vector of really long strings and I wanted to "free up" the memory being used by one of the strings in the middle of the vector.  This is *not* the perfect example because string *does* have a parameterless constructor, **but my type does not**.  Nevertheless this captures the spirit of my motivation for attempting this.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vec; // suppose I have a populated vector of strings

// Let's "reset" vec[3] to an empty string by moving it to a temp and destroying the temp
reset(std::move(vec[3]));
```

This moves the internals of `vec[3]` into the argument `t` of the `reset` function, and then, the destructor for `t` cleans up the internals.  This leaves `vec[3]` as an empty string.

The important part of this stunt is that we didn't need to construct an empty string.  This is important because my moveable type can be moved, but cannot be default constructed.

Other things I've tried:

```
{ std::move(somevar); } // this doesn't work
```

`std::move` all by itself doesn't work because you have to actually put the contents somewhere.

```
{ T t = std::move(somevar); } // works but cumbersome, and I have to name `T`
```

I'm just looking for a function I can call like `reset(somevar)`.  That consumes the soul of some object.  And the `std::move` part isn't *so* bad.  It is kind of like the authorization of *I expect you to die*.  So it's ok, in my mind, to say `reset(std::move(somevar))` But it doesn't finish the job.  So, maybe there's some other function that *does* do what I want.

So, is there a `std::consume_soul` that will accomplish the same as moving the contents of an object to a dummy and then destroing the dummy, leaving the original object behind with no contents (or whatever state the move constructor will leave it in)?

Maybe I'm unaware of some obvious approach?  I feel like there's likely some super easy way I'm just not aware of.

Comment: I think what you refer to as the "soul" of an object is typically just referred to as its "value".

Comment: If an object is moveable, it can almost always also have a default constructor which, at worse, creates an object that is equivalent to a moved-from instance. There is generally not a good reason to prevent default construction if moved-from instances can already exist. Then you can just do `somevar = {};`.

Comment: There is no built in function for this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I totally agree with you, that if it makes sense to steal its internals and leave it in an "empty" state, then there should be a default constructor that constructs it in an "empty" state.  But it just so happens that in this case it does not, and so I'm looking for a solution that leverages the fact that the move semantics *do* work.

Comment: You could make your version a little nicer by using `template <typename T> void release_memory(T&& obj) { T{std::move(obj)}; }` and then you could just call it like `release_memory(vec[3])`;

Comment: @Wyck You can change `reset` to `void reset(T& t)` and perform the `std::move` within `reset`. I'm not sure what you mean by "But it doesn't finish the job.".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I meant just writing `std::move(vec[3])` alone doesn't finish the job.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it sounds like you want a `clear()` function, and a private default constructor. Your move constructor and move assignment operator can access the private default constructor and do the swap internally.

Comment: Is your soul-less type valid? The expected operation of `std::move` is to leave the moved-from object in a valid state. Your interface should allow for the object to either be usable in a soul-less state, or to specify that the object is unusable after the move. Unusable and valid are not mutually exclusive, as long as the unusability is specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moving isn’t automatic, but non-const references are, so you can write

```
template<class T>
void dementor(T &t) {T(std::move(t));}
```

Comment: Great function name!  :)

Comment: Comparing your suggestion to the one from @NathanOliver, should it be `(T &t)` or `(T &&t)`?

Comment: @Wyck: If you want to support the case of consuming something provided to you as an xvalue (*i.e.*, a function that returns an rvalue reference), yes use a forwarding reference.  Prvalues of course are self-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great answer from @Davis Herring i'll provide a few more options you could use instead of moving to a temporary that might work better, dending on your usecase:

##### 1. Adding a `reset()` method for your type

The easiest solution would be to just add a `reset()` method to your type that clears all internal data.

Then you don't need to perform the move-to-temporary just for the side-effect of clearing your object.

##### 2. Using `std::optional`

This could also be a good use-case for [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

If you wrap your expensive class into an `std::optional` you can destroy the contained value anytime by calling `.reset()`. Additionally with optional you're able to check if a value currently exists.

This is even more powerful than moving to a temporary, since calling `reset()` on an optional will result in destructing the contained object. So whatever was inside it gets yeeted straight out of existence.

For your array case you could e.g. use:

```cpp
std::vector<std::optional<ExpensiveClass>> arr;

// add a new element
arr.emplace_back(std::in_place, /* constructor args for ExpensiveClass */);
// add a new (empty) element without needing a default constructor:
arr.push_back({});

// yeeting an instance out of existence
arr[0].reset();

// creating a new instance in an empty slot
arr[2].emplace(/* constructor args for ExpensiveClass */);

// checking if there's an element
if(arr[0]) { /* ... */ }

// using it
arr[0]->doSomething();
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ereaxo967)

That way you can easily control the lifetimes of the `ExpensiveClass` instances.

You also avoid the shenanigans of moving objects, namely:

- The move constructor / move assignment operator might actually copy some (or all) of the members instead of moving them
- The moved-from object only needs to be in a valid state, but can be indeterminate. So the only things that need to work on a moved-from object are (1) destructing it or (2) moving (or copying) another object into it.
  Example:

  ```cpp
     std::string a = "FOO";
     std::string b = "BAR";
     a = std::move(b);
     std::cout << b << std::endl;
  ```

  Could result in printing `FOO`, `BAR`, nothing or some random value. (depending on how move is implemented)

##### 3. Smart Pointers

If your objects are rather large and you'd prefer to allocate them on the heap you could exchange `std::optional` in the above examples with `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr`.

They also provide a `.reset()` function that will reset the pointer back to an empty state.